# CopyWebpackPlugin isn't copying files to output directory

Tags: webpack

Configuration in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
        from: 'src/app/**/*.json',
        to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        logLevel: 'trace'
    }
])
```

When I do this, I see the `json` files added to webpack's output:

```
src/app/core/error/i18n/en-AU.json   39 bytes          [emitted]
src/app/core/error/i18n/en-US.json   38 bytes          [emitted]
src/app/core/error/i18n/es-ES.json   36 bytes          [emitted]
```

... but they're not in my `dist` folder, and I see no logs from the plugin, despite the log level being set to `trace`.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: what about the full webpack config?  have u seen this one ? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/29

Comment: @RobertRowntree - The issue, in my case, turned out to be the order of the plugins. Thank you though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the order of my plugins was my issue. Changing the order to this fixed my issue:

```
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(/* options */),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(/* options */),
]
```

I guess something between the two of them doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

@MattGrande I am having a similar issue. My files show as being emitted but they are not actually being copied to dist folder.

Excerpt of compilation log:

> ```
>   Version: webpack 4.15.1         Time: 1824ms        Built at: 01/29/2020 3:51:51 PM
>                          Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>                        main.js   116 KiB       0  [emitted]         main
>                   CSS/main.css  76 bytes          [emitted]               Images/Uplink_Logo_Horiz.jpg   651 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
>               CSS/adminlte.css   708 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
>                     index.html   6.7 KiB          [emitted]
> ```

And my webpack config plugin looks like this:

> ```
> plugins: [
>     new CopyWebpackPlugin([
>         {
>             from: './Images/**',
>             to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
>             logLevel: 'trace'
>         },
>         {
>             from: './CSS/**',
>             to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
>             logLevel: 'trace'
>         }
>     ]),
>     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
>         template: './src/index.html'
>     })
> ],
> ```

I tried changing the order of CopyWebpackPlugin & HtmlWebpackPlugin to no luck. Did you do any other thing to solve this other than just changing the order.

Versions:

> "vue": "^2.6.11", "webpack": "^4.15.0", "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
>   "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1", "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't offer any help. Switching the order fixed it for me.

Comment: Did you check Robert's comment under my original question?

Comment: Found out the issue. The static files were not included in the VS project. Once I included them it started working. Thanks, for the help :)